# Editing unstructured file with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am editing a file using `sed` and have come across a problem, hopefully, a sed guru should be able to solve this.

I have an unstructured/partially structured file, which looks like below

```
##INFO=<ID=EX_TARGET,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="indicates whether a variant is within the exon pull down target boundaries">
##INFO=<ID=MULTI_ALLELIC,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="indicates whether a site is multi-allelic">
##source_20160901.1=vcf-subset(r940) -f -c HG02291 /net/isilonP/public/rw/ensembl/1000genomes/release-17/tmp/slicer/1.1-1000000.ALL.chr1.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  HG02291
1   10177   rs367896724 A   AC  100 PASS    AA=1    GT  1|0
1   10235   rs540431307 T   TA  100 PASS    XX=5    GT  0|0
1   10352   rs555500075 T   TA  100 PASS    JJ=7    GT  0|1
```

I have inserted a line to the file using the following command

`sed 's/.*##source_.*/\#\#INFO=\<ID=P_ID\,Number=1\,Type=String\,Description=\"Person Identifier\"\>\n&/' infile > outfile`

The output looks like this

```
##INFO=<ID=EX_TARGET,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="indicates whether a variant is within the exon pull down target boundaries">
##INFO=<ID=MULTI_ALLELIC,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="indicates whether a site is multi-allelic">
##INFO=<ID=P_ID,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Patient Identifier">
##source_20160901.1=vcf-subset(r940) -f -c HG02291 /net/isilonP/public/rw/ensembl/1000genomes/release-17/tmp/slicer/1.1-1000000.ALL.chr1.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  HG02291
1   10177   rs367896724 A   AC  100 PASS    AA=1    GT  1|0
1   10235   rs540431307 T   TA  100 PASS    XX=5    GT  0|0
1   10352   rs555500075 T   TA  100 PASS    JJ=7    GT  0|1
```

The next thing I want to do is, take the above file as input and append `;P_ID=12345` to column 8, that is `AA=1`,`XX=5`,`JJ=7`

The output should look like -

```
##INFO=<ID=EX_TARGET,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="indicates whether a variant is within the exon pull down target boundaries">
##INFO=<ID=MULTI_ALLELIC,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="indicates whether a site is multi-allelic">
##INFO=<ID=P_ID,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Patient Identifier">
##source_20160901.1=vcf-subset(r940) -f -c HG02291 /net/isilonP/public/rw/ensembl/1000genomes/release-17/tmp/slicer/1.1-1000000.ALL.chr1.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  HG02291
1   10177   rs367896724 A   AC  100 PASS    AA=1;P_ID=12345 GT  1|0
1   10235   rs540431307 T   TA  100 PASS    XX=5;P_ID=12345 GT  0|0
1   10352   rs555500075 T   TA  100 PASS    JJ=7;P_ID=12345 GT  0|1
```

So far, I have managed to select the column 8, but I am not sure how to put the updated lines back to the file after appending the information.

This is how I am selecting column 8 -

`sed -re '{s/^(\S+\s+){7}(\S+).*$/\2/;p}'`

Could any one pls help me solve this puzzle?

Thanks in advance!

Prashant

Comment: Take a look at GNU sed's option `-i`.

Comment: Neither #s, nor <s nor ,s are BRE metacharacters so not only do you not need to escape them but in some seds you can turn one of them into an ERE metacharacter by doing so. Learn which characters need to be escaped, it is NOT safe to just escape them all.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. I am very new to this, but I think sed/awk are very powerful editors and I wish to learn them. Currently, I am more into parallel processing technologies like Hadoop/Spark. Are there any good learning resources for awk + GNU Parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '
/^##source_/ { print "##INFO=<ID=P_ID,Number=1,Type=String,Description=\"Person Identifier\">" }
!/^#/ { $8 = $8 ";P_ID=12345" }
{ print }
' file
##INFO=<ID=EX_TARGET,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="indicates whether a variant is within the exon pull down target boundaries">
##INFO=<ID=MULTI_ALLELIC,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="indicates whether a site is multi-allelic">
##INFO=<ID=P_ID,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Person Identifier">
##source_20160901.1=vcf-subset(r940) -f -c HG02291 /net/isilonP/public/rw/ensembl/1000genomes/release-17/tmp/slicer/1.1-1000000.ALL.chr1.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5a.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  HG02291
1 10177 rs367896724 A AC 100 PASS AA=1;P_ID=12345 GT 1|0
1 10235 rs540431307 T TA 100 PASS XX=5;P_ID=12345 GT 0|0
1 10352 rs555500075 T TA 100 PASS JJ=7;P_ID=12345 GT 0|1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -re '{s/^((\S+ +){7}\S+)/\1;P_ID=12345/}' /tmp/so5.txt
```

where `/tmp/so5.txt` is your input file.

Comment: Brilliant, this works for my example. But, I had made up the example for simplicity purpose. The actual 8th column has random text without pattern, like `AA=.|||;AC=0;AF=0.000199681;AFR_AF=0.0008;AMR_AF=0;AN=2;DP=9632;EAS_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;NS=2504;SAS_AF=0;VT=SNP`

Comment: Basically, I need to add `;P_ID=12345` at the end of each statement in column 8.

Comment: @PRP: the regex in the answer is marginally more complex than you need; you should simply use: `sed -re '{s/^((\w+ +){7}\w+)/\1;P_ID=12345/}' /tmp/so5.txt` (looking for 7 sequences of word characters plus space characters followed by more word characters (the eighth column), and replace all that with what you got plus what you wanted added.

Comment: Thanks, my friend, but unfortunately that didn't work as expected. But, your answer was partly useful. Thank you once again!

Comment: So, most probably, we use different versions of sed.